# Powershell Invoke-RestMethod from VSTS build step fails with error 417

Tags: powershell, azure-pipelines-build-task, lametric

We bought ourselves a Lametric clock ([www.lametric.com](http://www.lametric.com)) which supports displaying messages sent to it through a [Web-API](http://lametric-documentation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference-docs/device-notifications.html). We would like to integrate this into our CI/CD queue. For that we have written a Powershell script, which will send a specified notification. This script works fine, when executed locally. When executed from a (local) VSTS Build Agent, it fails with a status code 417.

This is the powershell script:

```
Param (
    [Parameter(mandatory=$true)]
    [string] $BuildName,
    [Parameter(mandatory=$false)]
    [string] $Message
)


$Payload = '{"priority":"critical","icon_type":"alert","lifeTime":2000,"model":{"frames":[{"icon":"555","text":"' + $BuildName + ' BUILD FAILED! ' + $Message + '"}],"sound":{"category":"alarms","id":"alarm6","repeat":2},"cycles":0}}'

$request = @{uri = 'http://<ip-address>:8080/api/v2/device/notifications';
              Method = 'POST';
              Headers = @{Authorization = 'Basic <base64-encoded-credentials>='; "Content-Type" = 'application/json' }
       Body = $Payload
  }

invoke-restmethod @request
```

Can someone point us into the right direction, as to why we are experiencing this issue from the build step, but not locally?

Update 1:

If I strip out all variables it still failes.

Update 2:

- Changing `Invoke-RestMethod` to `Invoke-WebRequest` does not make a differnce.
- Invoking a `GET` request works
- Invoking a `POST` request fails with error 417

Comment: Back to debugging, methinks... what happens if you remove the various variables from your script and do the most basic version of your script?

Comment: Also, your title says `Invoke-WebRequest` but your code is using `Invoke-RestMethod`... just FYI `;-)`

Comment: @gvee thanks for catching that ;)

Comment: Are there any details in the error response? 417 is Expectation Failed, so you could always try tweaking the `Expect` header. But the server may be (ab)using that code for something else entirely.

Comment: Thank you @gvee for your initial input about `Invoke-WebRequest` vs. `Invoke-RestMethod`. I posted my working solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I found a solution to the problem. Seeing that sending a `GET` request with the option `-UseBasicParsing` worked fine, I tried combining the two requests one after the other. This did not work, if they were in two separate build steps.

However once I sent a `GET` request and followed it up with the above mentioned `POST` request, it magically worked. I don't know, why this works, but here is our current solution:

```
Param (
        [Parameter(mandatory=$true)]
        [string] $BuildName,
        [Parameter(mandatory=$false)]
        [string] $Message
)

$request = @{uri = 'http://<ip-address>:8080/api/v2';
            Method = 'GET';
            Headers = @{Authorization = 'Basic <base64-encoded-credentials>'; }
  }

invoke-webrequest -UseBasicParsing @request

$Payload = '{"priority":"critical","icon_type":"alert","lifeTime":2000,"model":{"frames":[{"icon":"555","text":"' + $BuildName + ' BUILD FAILED! ' + $Message + '"}],"sound":{"category":"alarms","id":"alarm6","repeat":2},"cycles":0}}'

$request = @{uri = 'http://<ip-address>:8080/api/v2/device/notifications';
            Method = 'POST';
            Headers = @{Authorization = 'Basic <base64-encoded-credentials>'; "Content-Type" = 'application/json' }
            Body = $Payload
  }

invoke-webrequest -UseBasicParsing @request
```

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT thanks for the reminder. Forgot to set up an automated reminder for when the 48-hours are up.

Comment: Hi I tried your code and it does not work with my lametric any chance you could explain how to get it to work. I replaced <ip-address> with my lametrics IP and where <base64-encoded-credentials>= i used `$Text = 'dev:my api key'
$Bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($Text)
$EncodedText =[Convert]::ToBase64String($Bytes)
$EncodedText` to get the credentials in coded but it just keeps failing with `invoke-webrequest : {
    "errors":[
        {
            "message":"Authorization is required"
        }
    ]
}`

Comment: @justinf you can use a tool such as Postman to create the base64 encoded string. You shouldn't encode that inline.

Comment: or you can use a site like: https://www.base64encode.org/ where you can paste your credentials ( dev:<your api key> ) and encode that.

Comment: Thanks I used base64encode.org to get what the string should be and it worked I then did the powershell like this to get the same result `$API = 'dev:exampl3415';$APIB  = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes("$API");$API64B = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($APIB)` It works now . I wanted to ask have you got a powershell example of how to delete/dismiss an alert . I could not figure that one out .

Comment: @justinf no, I don't have a PS script to dismiss the alarm. We have to do that manually on the clock itself. Please keep me updated, if you find a solution for that!

Comment: @justinf according to the Lametric documentation you can use a GET request to get all (pending) notifications followed by a DELETE request, where you send the ID of the notification to dismiss:
http://lametric-documentation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference-docs/device-notifications.html

Comment: @justinf see this question/answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50643326/how-to-dismiss-a-lametric-nofitication-using-powershell/50643327#50643327

Comment: Thanks I did find a solution , I am making some generic functions for Lametric I could send them your way may be you could improve them. Will put it on GIT when done

Comment: Perfect! Please post the link here in the comments! @justinf